# ReactPlayer is laggy to some videos

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState("");


useEffect(() => {
var video: String = "";
  async function fetchData() {
    const data = await getVideo.getStreamLinks(videoId, server);
    setUrl(data.url +);
  }
  fetchData();

}, []);


<ReactPlayer
        className="react-player"
        id="player"
        url={url}
        playing
        controls
        config={{
          file: {
            forceHLS: true,
          },
        }}
      />
```

This is my react player, there are instance where a video is taking too long to load and clicking a time stop takes forever to load. This issue only arise to specific videos but not all of them.

I want to make it so it plays the video smoothly, someone told me i should use caching but i dont know how can someone show me how, thank you